# I can't see see my database changes

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, sqlitemanager

I've entered some entries to my database and control the changes on SQLiteManager.
But, when I run my app, I stil see my old entries in the app.

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: "sqlite manager" what is it?

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Comment: how can it work with sqlite db on the remote device?

Answer (score 0):

When you provide your app with a prepopulatd database, then make external changes to that, it's not enough to put the updated db in the `assets` folder.

You must also delete the current db from the `databases` folder.

So, when your copy method will check for the database existence, it won't find it, and proceed with copying the new one in place.

Otherwise, the new database will remain in the `assets` folder and will never be copied over the old one.

This is why you get the old values instead of the updated ones.